# trying to scrape the data which is changing dynamically using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am having a website for which I need to scrape the data https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/OddsToday.aspx?IDSport=590 I need to scrape all the matches and their data when I click at once with one script so far I did for only one match after clicking but what I want is I need to click the every match and get the data in that match 
 So far my code is:

```
# Here using selenium for scraping
# importing necessary modules
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import mysql.connector
import pymysql

# the relevant url
url = 'https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/SubEventDetail?SubEventID=77106846'


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:/Users/SATYA/mysite/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
elements = [
    item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SEOddLnk.ng-binding")]
names = [
    item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SECQ.ng-binding")]
headings=names[0:3]+names[27:31]+names[85:87]+names[61:63]+names[88:90]


values = [
    item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SEOddsTQ.ng-binding")]
keys=values[0:8]+values[148:156]+values[244:248]+values[280:284]

vals=elements[0:8]+elements[148:156]+values[244:248]+values[280:284]
```

Comment: Iterate over the list of elements in the div of class CQ. Use the functionality of selenium to click on each of them and use the code you already have.

The most important is to understand the structure of the page you're scrapping before actually scrapping anything.

Comment: @PharoahJardin  see I wrote like this https://pastebin.com/hXd8tE5M for this link https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/OddsToday.aspx?IDSport=653

Comment: please help me @PharoahJardin

Comment: Describe the problem you want to solve and me or someone else may help you if there is a solution. I can't do all the work for you, though